# Drying concrete subfloor after water damage before installing laminate

Tags: concrete, flooring, moisture

We had a recent water leak that caused water to seep under our laminate floor. I pulled all the flooring up and removed the moisture barrier to reveal our concrete subfloor, which was moist.

It was a fairly slow leak, and it was mostly a small puddle across a large portion of the room, probably sat there around a few weeks before we noticed.

We've been running fans and dehumidifiers for over a week all day. The floor feels dry now, but a pinless moisture meter still pegs it at "100%" wet (unaffected concrete reads around 40-50%). Is this an accurate enough measurement to determine when to reinstall laminate (floating) again? If not, how long does it normally take concrete to dry after sitting in a puddle like that? We're running up our electric bill running this stuff 24/7, so I want to make sure I'm not doing it for no reason, but I'd also rather not walk around on concrete in my house for a month.

Comment: Does the flooring have any recommendations for concrete floor moisture content?  But I think that 100% is too high.  The moisture will come out eventually if you keep the room humidity low.

Comment: A few bucks worth of electricity now will be _far_ less expensive than replacing the floor again because you installed it over a wetter concrete surface than the new flooring calls for. Follow the mfgr recommendations on the dryness of the subfloor - call them (or hit up their website) to ask if you can't find it in their literature.